# Finding coordinates of maximum value in a grid

Tags: python-3.x, list

Given a grid of numbers like

```
g=[[2, 2, 2, 3, 2],
   [2, -1, -1, 3, 3],
   [3, 2, -1, 3, 3],
   [2, 4, 3, 3, 3],
   [-1, 2, 2, -1, 1]]
```

i am searching for the maximum value in that 2d list, which, in this example, is obivously 4.
To find that, `max(max(graph,key=max))` does the job (even though i know it calls max for the line with the maximum value twice, so it is not perfectly efficient)

But that is only half what i am looking for. I need the coordinates of this 4. I would like to have a short, efficient and pythonic piece of code like
`x, y = find_2d_max_index(g)` that gives me the position of the max number, without doing the triple max thing before. I want to avoid to use the `index()` method after finding the max as that would be very inefficient.

I looked into numpy argmax, but could not get it to work in this application with a 2d list.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all "rows" in `graph` have the same length (making `graph` equivalent to a 2D numpy array), then you can simply find the position of the largest value in a linear expansion and infer the coordinates from the position and the number of "columns" in `graph` (this is how numpy works under the hood).

```
import operator as op
from itertools import chain

ncol = len(graph[0])
flattened = chain.from_iterable(graph)
max_idx, max_val = max(enumerate(flattened), key=op.itemgetter(1))
row = max_idx // ncol
col = max_idx % ncol

# a simple sanity check
assert graph[row][col] == max_val
```

Comment: I like this solution, as it does not need any external libraries, and looks pretty efficient as it does not need the conversion to a numpy array to work with it.
I assume you forgot to define `ncol = len(graph[0])` ? That would need all rows to be the same length, but in my graphs this is a given.

Comment: @S.Bender "That would need all rows to be the same length" – yes, this is what I meant by "regular" (i.e. uniformly shaped) in the first sentence. I've rephrased the sentence to make it clearer. Thanks for pointing out the line I've missed.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `numpy` for this and the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) illustrates how.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2, 2, 2, 3, 2],
   [2, -1, -1, 3, 3],
   [3, 2, -1, 3, 3],
   [2, 4, 3, 3, 3],
   [-1, 2, 2, -1, 1]])

idx = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(a), a.shape)

a[idx]
>> 4
```

Explanation: We use `argmax` with no axis defined to get the index of the maximum item if the array were one flat array, in this case it would be `16` as the number `4` would be the `16th` element of this long array. Then we provide the shape of our actual array to `np.unravel_index` and the index of the max item, in this case `16` and it determines based on the shape of the array, the coordinates of this number.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `max` and `enumerate` built-in fucntions:

```
(col, val), row = max(map(lambda x: (max(enumerate(x[1]), key= lambda x: x[1]), x[0]), enumerate(g)), key=lambda x: x[0][1])
print(col, row)
```

output:

```
1 3
```

to break this apart you could use:

```
from typing import List, Tuple

# didn't get the inner functions out to be easy to read/understand
def max_row_with_column_and_row_coordinates(row_list: tuple):
        """Given row number and the value return the max on each row

        with the row number and column number
        """

        def get_max_row(row_list: Tuple[int, List]) -> Tuple[Tuple[int, int], int]:
            row_number, inner_list = row_list
            # will give you the col number and the actual number/value
            col_value = enumerate(inner_list)  # (col_number, number)

            def get_value(col_value: Tuple[int, int]) -> int:
                col_number, value = col_value
                return value

            col_max_row = max(col_value, key=get_value)

            return col_max_row, row_number # ((col_number, value), row_number)

        def get_the_value(col_value_row: Tuple[Tuple[int, int], int]) -> int:
            (col_number, value), row_numebr = col_value_row # unpack
            return value

        max_row_with_coordinates = map(get_max_row, row_list)

        return max(max_row_with_coordinates, key=get_the_value)  # ((col_number, value), row_numebr) 


def max_value_with_coordinates(g: List[List]) -> Tuple[Tuple[int, int], int]:
    """Return the max on each row keeping the coordinates of each value.

    The coordinates are given by the enumerate built-in function.
    """

    row_list = enumerate(g) # will give you the row number: (row_numebr, inner_list)
    return max_row_with_column_and_row_coordinates(row_list) # ((col_number, value), row_numebr) 

(col, val), row = max_value_with_coordinates(g)

print(col, row)
```

output:

```
1 3
```

Comment: while this solution may seem clever it is not readable. can you please break this apart so it is understandable. one-liners shouldn't be recommended answers unless they are short and concise

Comment: @gold_cy I hope is better now

Comment: But I think the one line is better, is the same logic as OP is doing to get the max value  what is doing extra is just keeping the coordinates of the max value

Answer (score -1):

Just do the following:

```
max(map(max, graph))
```

This will call `max` only once for each row and then take the max from the results.

Comment: This is a nice solution to get the four, but how does this get me its coordniates?